# Doubt with List<Generic> Explicit Cast

Tags: java, generics, casting

I don't understand why in some cases I can make an explicit cast and in other cases I can not. Thanks to all!

```
//DAreaLabel extends Message 

//This Code Works
List<Message> list1 = (List<Message>)
        Arrays.asList((Message[]) getPageRecords(getClasspath(), methodName, object));

DAreaLabel areaLabel = (DAreaLabel)
        ((List<Message>) Arrays.asList((Message[]) getPageRecords(getClasspath(), methodName, object))).get(0);

//This Code does not Work
List<DAreaLabel> list2 = (List<DAreaLabel>)
        Arrays.asList((Message[]) getPageRecords(getClasspath(), methodName, object));
```

Comment: Can you format that so it is readable?

Comment: What is the error the compiler gives?

Comment: Minor nitpick, but I see this a lot from people for whom English is not their primary language: If you don't understand something, you have a question, not a doubt. If you think something might be wrong, you have a doubt.

Answer (score 5):

Your latter cast doesn't work, essentially because generics are not covariant.

That is, assuming `DAreaLabel` is a subtype of `Message`, then you can cast a Message into a DAreaLabel, but you **cannot** cast a `List<Message>` into a `List<DAreaLabel>`, which is effectively what you are trying to do in the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `DAreaLabel` is (presumably) a subclass of `Message`, `List<DAreaLabel>` is not a subclass of `List<Message>`. The [Java Tutorial's generics trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) says why. Thus the last case does not compile.  The first case also should not need casting at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast a `List<Message>` into a `List<? extends Message>`, which could then reference a `List<DAreaLabel>`. However, instances retrieved would still need to be cast to `DAreaLabel` to use that class's features.